# How can you specialize broadcasting in julia?

Tags: julia, array-broadcasting

I want to write custom method for the broadcast operation

```
f.(v)
```

for my custom function `f`. What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to google for julia interfaces (not broadcasting) to find the [relevant manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interfaces-broadcasting)

excerpt:

| Methods to implement | Brief description |
| --- | --- |
| `Base.BroadcastStyle(::Type{SrcType}) = SrcStyle()` | Broadcasting behavior of `SrcType` |
| `Base.similar(bc::Broadcasted{DestStyle}, ::Type{ElType})` | Allocation of output container |
| **Optional methods** |  |
| `Base.BroadcastStyle(::Style1, ::Style2) = Style12()` | Precedence rules for mixing styles |
| `Base.axes(x)` | Declaration of the indices of `x`, as per `axes(x)`. |
| `Base.broadcastable(x)` | Convert `x` to an object that has `axes` and supports indexing |
| **Bypassing default machinery** |  |
| `Base.copy(bc::Broadcasted{DestStyle})` | Custom implementation of `broadcast` |
| `Base.copyto!(dest, bc::Broadcasted{DestStyle})` | Custom implementation of `broadcast!`, specializing on `DestStyle` |
| `Base.copyto!(dest::DestType, bc::Broadcasted{Nothing})` | Custom implementation of `broadcast!`, specializing on `DestType` |
| `Base.Broadcast.broadcasted(f, args...)` | Override the default lazy behavior within a fused expression |
| `Base.Broadcast.instantiate(bc::Broadcasted{DestStyle})` | Override the computation of the lazy broadcast's axes |

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/overload-broadcasting-for-custom-struct/42240) thread useful. In short, the `Broadcast.broadcasted` structure allows you specialize specific cases of broadcasted operations. For example, consider the case where `v` is a vector, then the overload for the operation `f.(v)` would look like this:

```
function Broadcast.broadcasted(::typeof(f), v::Vector{T}) where T
    # Write your custom implementation here to compute the output
    ...
    
    return output
end
```

If you have multiple cases you want to specialize, then you either have to do it one-by-one, or you write custom broadcasting styles as another answer mentioned.